# How to make commands defined by \def behave as strings?

Tags: tex-core

I found this issue while designing a complex image embedding command, as one perhaps may guess from the names of the various auxiliary commands defined in the code below: also the structure of the code reflects the complexity of the design. The command `\multipicts` below accepts a variable number of arguments by using the  `\forcsvlist` command. Each argument consists of a couple of comma separated variables enclosed between curly braces. The first variable is the name of a .jpg, .png, .ps or .eps image, while the second one is a string defining the crop margins for the same image: those variables are meant to be respectively passed as `\showpicname` and `\showcroplims` commands to a `\includegraphics` command, in the following way

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio,trim=\noexpand\showcroplims, clip]{\noexpand\showpicname}
```

However, this is not done in the test code below, which is limited just to define `\showpicname` and `\showcroplims`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{paper} % Preamble

% structure settings
\usepackage{etoolbox}  
\usepackage{ifthen}    
\newcounter{cmdargs}   % Number of variable arguments for user defined commands
\newcounter{argnum}    % index of an argument in a list
\newcommand{\showpicname}{{\picn@me}}    % First parameter of the argument couple to be extracted
\newcommand{\showcroplims}{{\crop@lims}} % Second parameter of the argument couple to be extracted
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand*{\argscount}[1]{% 
  \stepcounter{cmdargs}
}

\newcommand*{\xpargs}[1]{% Arguments expander
  \stepcounter{argnum}
  \ifthenelse{\value{argnum}=1}
  {\gdef\picn@me{#1}}  % If the value of argnum is 1 then the parameter parsed is the picture name
  {\gdef\crop@lims{#1}} % Otherwise it is the crop margin string
}

\newcommand*{\addimage}[1]{% Image insertion (via multipicts)
  \setcounter{argnum}{0}
  \forcsvlist{\xpargs}{#1}\\
  The argument is\ \{#1\}:\\
  The parameters of the argument are\ \noexpand{\showpicname}\ and\ \noexpand{\showcroplims}.\\
  \setcounter{argnum}{0}
}

\newcommand{\multipicts}[1]{% Multipicture environment
  \setcounter{cmdargs}{0}
  \forcsvlist{\argscount}{#1} % Count the arguments of invocation
  \forcsvlist{\addimage}{#1}\\% Embed the "image"
  This is a test: the number of iterations done is \arabic{cmdargs}.
}


\begin{document}

\noindent
First call of the macro:\\
\noindent
\multipicts{{a,0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm},{b,c},{c,d},{d,e}}\\[2ex]


\noindent
Second call of the macro:\\
\noindent
\multipicts{{2016-05-11_Valvola_intercettazione_lucchettata-low_dim.jpg,0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm},{b,c},{c,d},{d,e}}

\end{document}
```

The image below shows the result of the compilation of this code
[image]

When `\pic@name` is a simple alphabetic character everything seems fine, while when it is a true picture name the command breaks. It seems that the underscore '_' is interpreted as a math mode command, despite the `\noexpand` placed in order to avoid this. In sum, my question is: how can I make such commands behave like simple strings?

Comment: `{` is not expandable so `\noexpand{` is the same as `{` (similarly the math subscrpt `_` isn't expandable so `\noexpand_` is the same as `_`)

Comment: Maybe try `\usepackage[extendedchars,space]{grffile}`

Comment: also it is not clear why you are using `\noexpand`  here `trim=\noexpand\showcroplims` trim is expecting a space separated list of dimensions and `\noexpand` would in most cases stop that working.

Comment: This seems to be an XY question: you don't want to print the file name, I guess, but rather do `\includegraphics`. I think it's better to show the real macros, rather than the testing (for which you can use `\detokenize{#1}`).

Comment: @David Carlisle and @egreg. Probably I misunderstood the command behavior in TEX: perhaps if I try to call directly `\includegraphics` everything works fine. Unfortunately, the time allowed for this work in this week is terminated an I must stop working on this command: however I will try the suggestions of egreg and report the results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the [suggestion in the comment to the question by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396803/how-to-make-commands-defined-by-def-behave-as-strings/403883#comment987182_396803), i.e. I used the `\detokenize` command where needed: in particular, note that I had to use the command twice, once in the assigning the value of `\pic@name` by `\gdef` in the macro `\xpargs`, and once while parsing the arguments of `\addimage`, in order to "inactivate" the couple of arguments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{paper}

% Preamble

% structure settings
\usepackage{calc}      % programmer's tools of the trade
\usepackage{etoolbox}  % programmer's tools of the trade, II
\usepackage{ifthen}    % programmer's tools of the trade, III
\newcounter{cmdargs}   % Number of variable arguments for user defined commands
\newcounter{argnum}    % index of an argument in a list
\newcommand{\showpicname}{{\picn@me}}    % First parameter of the argument couple to be extracted
\newcommand{\showcroplims}{{\crop@lims}} % Second parameter of the argument couple to be extracted
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand*{\argscount}[1]{% 
  \stepcounter{cmdargs}
}

\newcommand*{\xpargs}[1]{% Arguments expander
  \stepcounter{argnum}
  \ifthenelse{\value{argnum}=1}
  {\gdef\picn@me{\detokenize{#1}}}  % If the value of argnum is 1 then the parameter parsed is the first one
  {\gdef\crop@lims{#1}} % Otherwise it is the second
}

\newcommand*{\addimage}[1]{% Image insertion (via multipicts)
  \setcounter{argnum}{0}
  \forcsvlist{\xpargs}{#1}\\
  The argument is\ \{\detokenize{#1}\}:\\
  The parameters of the argument are \showpicname\ and \showcroplims.\\
  \setcounter{argnum}{0}
}

\newcommand{\multipicts}[1]{% Multipicture environment
  \setcounter{cmdargs}{0}
  \forcsvlist{\argscount}{#1} % Count the arguments of invocation
  \forcsvlist{\addimage}{#1}\\% Embed the "image"
  This is a test: the number of iterations done is \arabic{cmdargs}.
}


\begin{document}

\noindent
First call of the macro:\\
\noindent
\multipicts{{a,0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm},{b,c},{c,d},{d,e}}\\[2ex]


\noindent
Second call of the macro:\\
\noindent
\multipicts{{2016-05-11_Valvola_intercettazione_lucchettata-low_dim.jpg,0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm},{b,c},{c,d},{d,e}}

\end{document}
```

This is the result I get after running the code:

[image]

Finally, I must say that now I agree fully with egreg: while using LaTEX it is simpler not to test an algorithm with a dummy procedure, but to try it directly. To my opinion, this is a consequence of the peculiar structure of a LaTEX commands.