# How correctly pass to a command a tuple of parameters parsed from an arbitrarily long list?

Tags: graphics, key-value

Following [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396803/how-to-make-commands-defined-by-def-behave-as-strings), I am continuing the design of a complex image embedding command and I have still problems in managing joint groups of parameters I need to pass to other commands in each single iteration. This is the code I am designing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{paper}

% Preamble

% structure settings

\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{calc}      % programmer's tools of the trade
\usepackage{etoolbox}  % programmer's tools of the trade, II
\usepackage{ifthen}    % programmer's tools of the trade, III
\newcounter{cmdargs}   % Number of variable arguments for user defined commands
\newcounter{argnum}    % index of an argument in a list
\newlength{\picsheight}  % height of multipics picture table
\newlength{\picswidht}   % height of multipics picture table
\newlength{\captheight}  % height of multipict caption text
\newlength{\pboxheight}  % height of multipict box (text height)

\newcommand*{\xpargs}[1]{
  \stepcounter{argnum}
  \ifthenelse{\value{argnum}=1}
  {\gdef\picn@me{#1}}{\gdef\crop@lims{#1}}
}

\newcommand{\showpicname}{\picn@me}    % First parameter of the argument couple to be extracted
\newcommand{\showcroplims}{\crop@lims} % Second parameter of the argument couple to be extracted

\newcommand*{\addimage}[1]{% Image insertion via \multipic(t)s
  \setcounter{argnum}{0}
  \forcsvlist{\xpargs}{#1}
  \hspace*{\fill}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth-3em,keepaspectratio,\showcroplims,clip]{\showpicname}\hspace*{\fill}
  \\[2ex]
  \setcounter{argnum}{0}
}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\multipicts}[3]{% Multipicture environment
  \settototalheight{\captheight}{\parbox{.5\textwidth}{#2}} % Caption height
  \settototalheight{\picsheight}{\parbox{.5\textwidth{\forcsvlist{\addimage}{#3}}} % Picture column height
  \ifthenelse {\lengthtest{\captheight > \picsheight}} % Check who requires more height of text
  {\setlength{\pboxheight}{\captheight}}{\setlength{\pboxheight}{\picsheight}}  % then correspondingly set the picture box height
  \ifthenelse {\lengthtest{\pboxheight > \textheight}} {Picture box height is bigger than the maximum textblock height admitted in a single page: \the\pboxheight$>$\the\textheight}
  {\noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
      \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{#1}
      % \fbox{
      \parbox[t][\pboxheight][c]{0.5\linewidth}{\forcsvlist{\addimage}{#3}}%}
      \hfill
      % \fbox{
        \parbox[t][\pboxheight][c]{0.5\linewidth}{%
          #2\\
          \ifthenelse {\lengthtest{\pboxheight > \textheight}}
          {\the\pboxheight\ $>$ \the\textheight} {The picture box is \the\pboxheight, smaller than \the\textheight, which is the maximum allowable text height.}}%}
    \end{minipage}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\multipicts{General power supply isolator}{General power supply isolator {\bf (A)}, which can be secured with a padlock.}{{2016-05-11_Valvola_intercettazione_lucchettata-low_dim.jpg,0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm},{2016-05-11_Valvola_intercettazione_lucchettata-low_dim.jpg,0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm},{2016-05-11_Valvola_intercettazione_lucchettata-low_dim.jpg,0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm},{2016-05-11_Valvola_intercettazione_lucchettata-low_dim.jpg,0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm}}

\end{document}
```

The sample image I have used is the following one:
[image]

A brief description of how the command works (or should do) is reported below:

- The command accepts as input parameters two texts plus an unspecified number of couple parameters. The first parameter of each input couple is a picture name, while the second one are its crop limits.
- The each couple parameter is expanded as two separated ones `pin@me` and `\crop@lims` by the `\xpargs` function: both of them are passed to a `\includegraphics` command during the same iteration.
- The full parsing utilizes the `\forcsvlist` library function.
- The `\addimage` command is first launched inside a `\settototalheight` command in order to estimate the full height of the picture box: this height is compared to the height of text which should be present on one side of the picture(s). Then `\pboxheight` parameter is defined accordingly and a `minipage` environment is created with the chosen dimensions and two parboxes of the same height and half of its width are cheated: one is filled with the picture(s) while the other is filled with the text.
- A short caption is added to the list of figures `.lof` file.

The command seems to work: however, while `picn@ame` is correctly passed to the the `\includegraphics` command, the crop limits are not. The parameter  `\crop@lims` is not acknowledged by `keyval`, which gives the following error message (found also in the `.log` file):

```
ERROR: Package keyval Error: 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm undefined.

--- TeX said ---

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.66 ...tata-low_dim.jpg,0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm}}

--- HELP ---
No help available
```

In sum, my question is: "How is the best way to pass couples (or tuples) of parameters parsed from an arbitrarily long list, to another command during each single iteration?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are passing the key values incorrectly. At first the option is `trim= 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm` and not `0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm`. At second you can't hide the value in a command for the trim key -- the parser must see the spaces. So you should expand it before calling includegraphics.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\def\showcroplims{4cm 4cm 1cm 1cm}

\edef\next{\noexpand\includegraphics[width=\noexpand\linewidth-3em,keepaspectratio,trim=\showcroplims,clip]{example-image-A}}
\next

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I completely forgot the `trim=` part of the parameter, but also I see that the second problem you showed me how to solve is not trivial at all.

Comment: `\noexpand` is redundant before `\linewidth`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a new answer: I just want to share how I applied to my problem [the resolutive suggestion of Ms Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404856/99071). It is not sufficient to change the `\addimage` macro in order to expand `\includegraphics` and all its parameters at the right time, following her advice: also the parsing macro `\xpargs` must be changed, using `\xdef` to define and immediately expand the parameters `\picname` and `\croplims` to be readily available in their expanded form. The resulting code, a little bit cleaned, is reported below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{paper}

% Preamble

% structure settings

\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{calc}      % programmer's tools of the trade
\usepackage{etoolbox}  % programmer's tools of the trade, II
\usepackage{ifthen}    % programmer's tools of the trade, III
\newcounter{argnum}    % index of an argument in a list
\newlength{\picsheight}  % height of multipics picture table
\newlength{\picswidht}   % height of multipics picture table
\newlength{\captheight}  % height of multipict caption text
\newlength{\pboxheight}  % height of multipict box (text height)

\newcommand*{\xpargs}[1]{
  \stepcounter{argnum}
  \ifthenelse{\value{argnum}=1}
  {\xdef\picname{#1}}%
  {\xdef\croplims{#1}}%
}

\newcommand*{\addimage}[1]{            % Image insertion via \multipic(t)s
  \setcounter{argnum}{0}
  \forcsvlist{\xpargs}{#1}
  \xdef\next{\noexpand\includegraphics[width=\linewidth-.5em,keepaspectratio,\croplims,clip]{\picname}}
  \next\hspace*{\fill}
  \\[.2ex]
}

\newcommand{\multipicts}[3]{     % Multipicture environment
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
  \settototalheight{\captheight}{\parbox{.5\textwidth}{#2}}      % Caption height
  \settototalheight{\picsheight}{\parbox{.5\textwidth}{\forcsvlist{\addimage}{#3}}} % Picture column height
  \ifthenelse {\lengthtest{\captheight > \picsheight}}     % Check who requires more height of text
  {\setlength{\pboxheight}{\captheight}}{\setlength{\pboxheight}{\picsheight} % then correspondingly set the picture box height
  \ifthenelse {\lengthtest{\pboxheight > \textheight}} {Picture box height is bigger than the maximum textblock height admitted in a single page: \the\pboxheight$>$\the\textheight}
  {\noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
      \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{#1}
      \parbox[t][\pboxheight][c]{0.5\linewidth}{\forcsvlist{\addimage}{#3}}
      \hfill
      \parbox[t][\pboxheight][c]{0.5\linewidth}{%
        #2\\
        \ifthenelse {\lengthtest{\pboxheight > \textheight}}
        {\the\pboxheight\ $>$ \the\textheight} {The picture box is \the\pboxheight, smaller than \the\textheight, which is the maximum allowable text height.}}
    \end{minipage}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\multipicts{General power supply isolator}{General power supply isolator {\bf (A)}, which can be secured with a padlock.}{{2016-05-11_Valvola_intercettazione_lucchettata-low_dim.jpg,trim=0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm},{2016-05-11_Valvola_intercettazione_lucchettata-low_dim.jpg,trim=0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm},{2016-05-11_Valvola_intercettazione_lucchettata-low_dim.jpg,trim=0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm},{2016-05-11_Valvola_intercettazione_lucchettata-low_dim.jpg,trim=0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm 0.5cm}}
\end{document}
```